# Trying to limit the results of a group by query to a range of dates

Tags: oracle, date, common-table-expression

I'm trying to limit a query's results to the latest 14 distinct PROCESS_DATE dates. To do this, I have used a CTE expression to retrieve the latest and earliest dates for the date range

With these 2 values, I would like to plug them into a group by statement so that I will get results between the two dates

But I am getting this error when I run the query in Oracle

> > ORA-00904: "MAX_PROCESS_DATE": invalid identifier
> > 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> > *Cause:
> > *Action:
> > Error at Line: 24 Column: 60

Line: 24 Column: 60 is the **WHERE PROCESS_DATE >= MIN_PROCESS_DATE AND .... MAX_PROCESS_DATE** part of the Group By statement

If this is a wrong way to go about this task, please pardon me and suggest a better query. If it's on the right track, how would I fix it so it will run successfully?

```
WITH cteQUERYRANGE AS
(
   SELECT MAX(PROCESS_DATE) AS MAX_PROCESS_DATE, MIN(PROCESS_DATE) AS MIN_PROCESS_DATE FROM
   (
   SELECT DISTINCT PROCESS_DATE FROM PAYMENTS
   ORDER BY PROCESS_DATE DESC
   FETCH FIRST 14 ROWS ONLY
   )
)
SELECT PROGRAM_CODE AS PROGRAM, BWE_DATE AS "BWE DATE", PROCESS_DATE AS "PROCESSED DATE", GROSS_AMOUNT AS ENTITLEMENTS, FPUC, LWA
FROM PAYMENTS
WHERE PROCESS_DATE >= MIN_PROCESS_DATE AND PROCESS_DATE <= MAX_PROCESS_DATE
GROUP BY PROGRAM_CODE, BWE_DATE, PROCESS_DATE, GROSS_AMOUNT, FPUC, LWA
ORDER BY PROCESS_DATE DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like this (see 3 comments within code):

```
WITH ctequeryrange AS(SELECT MAX(process_date)     AS max_process_date,
                             MIN(process_date)     AS min_process_date
                      FROM(SELECT DISTINCT process_date
                           FROM payments
                           ORDER BY process_date DESC
                           FETCH FIRST 14 ROWS ONLY)
)
SELECT DISTINCT program_code  AS program,         --> distinct
       bwe_date      AS "BWE DATE",
       process_date  AS "PROCESSED DATE",
       gross_amount  AS entitlements,
       fpuc,
       lwa
FROM payments cross join ctequeryrange             --> cross join
WHERE process_date >= min_process_date
      AND process_date <= max_process_date
ORDER BY process_date DESC;                        --> no group by
```

- if you want to use columns from a CTE, you have to "reference" it, somehow. As it returns only one row, cross join is *safe*
- as there are no aggregates in your query, no need to `GROUP BY` - `DISTINCT` would do

Though, your `fetch first 14 rows` won't result in 14 rows (if that was your intention) as CTE itself returns only one row.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I forgot I did not need a group by, so it's all good